# Cannot import functions in from one directory's subfolder to other pyhton files in same parent directories sub folders. How do I use init.py files

Tags: python-3.x, dockerfile, data-science, docker-container

parent_folder /
subfolder1 /
subsubfolder1/
a.py
b.py
subsubfolder2/
c.py
d.py
e.py
subfolder2 /
subsubfolder2/
f.py
g.py
subfolder3 /
h.py
i.py
g.py

I want to import the functions from files h,i,g to all the subsubfolders py files. Can any one help me how do I do that.
I have tried using sys.path.insert(0 , 'path')
from h import funct1  , from g import funct1. It works
II get this error ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package when I do from .h import funct1 and I also want to Implement this in docker files. Is there any other way?
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

For your case it is best to use sys:-
for example to import in a.py use:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'../../subfolder3')
import h,i,g
```

Here we can use relative path in sys, '..' indicates moving one folder back

For Docker it is best to use relative path as:

```
import sys,os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(sys.path[0],'../../subfolder3'))
import h,i,g
```

This would work for docker. Please try and let me know if it works.

Comment: Hey  , Yes this solution works on local and I have used it I am looking any alternative  way to import files without mentioning path ?

Comment: The other way is to use __init__.py file inside a directory, but this only works if the file importing is present in the same folder as the package directory. The above method works if you can specify absolute path even in remote servers and not just with local machine.

Comment: If I add an absolute path in py files to be executed in docker it will work you are saying . Will try it once , Thanks .

Comment: @sapnaSingh Please see the edits and try relative path in docker. It would work I guess.